# Load new contents in Jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, servlets, modal-dialog

I am creating a JQuery Modal dialog by opening a JSP in it. This JSP recieves data posted form a servlet. Now there is a section with href links for data and when I click on the href, I want this JQuery Modal Dialog to stay as it is and be loaded with new content. Right now, this window closes and a page with the new data is being displayed. Any ideas?

Currently I have a JSP named MetricReports.jsp, invoked from MetricSelect.html.
Am opening the JQuery dialog as follows from MetricSelect.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    renderjdialog('#jdialog','Syslog/Trap Analytics');
    $("#SubmitBtn").die();
    $("#SubmitBtn").live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url:'MetricsReport', 
            data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loading").show();   
        },
            success: function(response) {
            showDialog(response);
            $('#loading').hide();           
        }
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

The JS code is as below:

```
var jDialog = undefined;
function renderjdialog(selector, title) {
jDialog = $(selector);
jDialog.dialog({
    title : title || 'Dialog',
    autoOpen : false,
    modal : true,
    width : 1070,
    height : 600
});
}
function  showDialog(content) {
content = content || '';
jDialog.html(content);
jDialog.dialog("open"); 
};
function  closeDialog(content) {
alert("Close performed");
jDialog.dialog("close");
parent.reloadContent();
location.reload(true);
};
```

Now in MetricsReport, is a servlet redirecting to a JSP. This JSP sometimes contains HREF links. At the moment, if I click on the HREF links, it redirects to a new page closing this JQUERY Dialog.

What I want to do is to reload the new page in the existing JQUERY Dialog. Is that possible? If yes, how do we do it?

Comment: You should provide some code examples presenting what you've done and at which point you are stuck.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry. Anyway added the same in my main query.